# How to use an email URL with a password which contains slash character of `/`

Tags: python, django, amazon-ses

For a Django app, I'm trying to set environment variable `EMAIL_URL` to `smtp://username:password@email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:587/?tls=True` where `password` contains slash character of `/`.

Amazon SES is giving me a password which contains `/` character for some reason.

For example:

```sh
export EMAIL_URL="smtp://AKIAYZT73XCKGD:BFB6UvkMgn9dniEGQZc/xM/KDS9Agc/S2@email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:587/?tls=True"
```

And then running:

```sh
python3.9 manage.py runserver
```

But I'm receiving an error:

> ValueError: Port could not be cast to integer value as 'BFB6UvkMgn9dniEGQZc'

Error is thrown at this file:

```
myapp-venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dj_email_url.py
```

At `'EMAIL_PORT': url.port,` statement of this function:

```py
def parse(url):
    """Parses an email URL."""

    conf = {}

    url = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
    qs = urllib.parse.parse_qs(url.query)

    # Remove query strings
    path = url.path[1:]
    path = path.split('?', 2)[0]

    # Update with environment configuration
    conf.update({
        'EMAIL_FILE_PATH': path,
        'EMAIL_HOST_USER': unquote(url.username),
        'EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD': unquote(url.password),
        'EMAIL_HOST': url.hostname,
        'EMAIL_PORT': url.port,
        'EMAIL_USE_SSL': False,
        'EMAIL_USE_TLS': False,
    })

    if url.scheme in SCHEMES:
        conf['EMAIL_BACKEND'] = SCHEMES[url.scheme]

    # ...

    return conf
```

#### Tried

I tried to escape the `/` with `\` but it didn't work!

#### Tried

As suggested by @bdbd, tried using this statement:

```
EMAIL_URL = urllib.parse.quote(EMAIL_URL)
```

Right before calling `dj_email_url.parse`:

```
email_config = dj_email_url.parse(EMAIL_URL)
```

But the problem is, in that case, the resulted `email_config` won't have a key of `EMAIL_BACKEND`. I mean, this statement cannot be evaluated:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = email_config["EMAIL_BACKEND"]
```

#### Code

The code to call `dj_email_url.parse` is this:

```py
EMAIL_URL = os.environ.get("EMAIL_URL")

### Amazon SES password contains slash character,
### trying to fix resulted errors.
### Unfortunately, didn't work.
#EMAIL_URL = urllib.parse.quote(EMAIL_URL)

email_config = dj_email_url.parse(EMAIL_URL)

EMAIL_FILE_PATH = email_config["EMAIL_FILE_PATH"]
EMAIL_HOST_USER = email_config["EMAIL_HOST_USER"]
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = email_config["EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD"]
EMAIL_HOST = email_config["EMAIL_HOST"]
EMAIL_PORT = email_config["EMAIL_PORT"]
EMAIL_BACKEND = email_config["EMAIL_BACKEND"]
EMAIL_USE_TLS = email_config["EMAIL_USE_TLS"]
EMAIL_USE_SSL = email_config["EMAIL_USE_SSL"]
```

#### Worked?

Based on @JPG answer, I replaced `/` character in password with `%2F` when setting environment variable:

```sh
### Replace this:
export EMAIL_URL="smtp://AKIAYZT73XCKGD:BFB6UvkMgn9dniEGQZc/xM/KDS9Agc/S2@email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:587/?tls=True"

### With this:
export EMAIL_URL="smtp://AKIAYZT73XCKGD:BFB6UvkMgn9dniEGQZc%2FxM%2FKDS9Agc%2FS2@email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:587/?tls=True"
```

Looks like it resolved the error without the need to modify the code! Needs more testing.

Comment: Try with `url = urllib.parse.quote(EMAIL_URL)` before passing it to `parse`

Comment: @bdbd I updated the post by the new observation after modifying the code :)

Comment: What was the output? Also it was using `urllib.parse.urlparse(url)` before right?

Comment: @bdbd I updated the post with the code calling `dj_email_url.parse` thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, normalize your password part (or the part that contains the slash)

```py
In [2]: from urllib.parse import quote

In [3]: pwd = "BFB6UvkMgn9dniEGQZc/xM/KDS9Agc/S2"

In [4]: quote(pwd, safe="")
Out[4]: 'BFB6UvkMgn9dniEGQZc%2FxM%2FKDS9Agc%2FS2'
```

Now, we have got the ***normalized password string***. Then, replace the password part of the URL with this new password. So, it will become as,

```
export EMAIL_URL="smtp://AKIAYZT73XCKGD:BFB6UvkMgn9dniEGQZc%2FxM%2FKDS9Agc%2FS2@email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:587/?tls=True"
```

---

### Example

```py
In [16]: from urllib.parse import unquote

In [17]: env("EMAIL_URL")
Out[17]: 'smtp://AKIAYZT73XCKGD:BFB6UvkMgn9dniEGQZc%2FxM%2FKDS9Agc%2FS2@email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:587/?tls=True'

In [18]: env.email_url('EMAIL_URL')
Out[18]: 
{'EMAIL_FILE_PATH': '',
 'EMAIL_HOST_USER': 'AKIAYZT73XCKGD',
 'EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD': 'BFB6UvkMgn9dniEGQZc/xM/KDS9Agc/S2',
 'EMAIL_HOST': 'email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com',
 'EMAIL_PORT': 587,
 'EMAIL_BACKEND': 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend',
 'OPTIONS': {'TLS': 'True'}}

In [19]: unquote(env("EMAIL_URL"))
Out[19]: 'smtp://AKIAYZT73XCKGD:BFB6UvkMgn9dniEGQZc/xM/KDS9Agc/S2@email-smtp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com:587/?tls=True'
```

Comment: I just replaced `/` character in password with `%2F` manually, when exporting environment variable. Looks like it worked, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

From [dj-email-url docs](https://github.com/migonzalvar/dj-email-url#https://github.com/migonzalvar/dj-email-url#supported-backends).

> To use characters that have a special meaning in an URL (think of &)
> you should use [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). For example, m&m would become
> m%26m.
>
> Because the percent character itself (%) serves as the indicator for
> percent-encoded octets, it must be percent-encoded as %25.
>
> ````
> >>> from urllib.parse import quote_plus
> >>> import dj_email_url
> >>> quote_plus("!@#$%^&*") '%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26%2A'
> >>> dj_email_url.parse("smtp://user:%21%40%23%24%25%5E%26%2A@localhost")["EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD"]
> '!@#$%^&*' ```
> ````